# 2000 mazda 626 v6

Tags: brakes, idle, mazda-626

My Mazda shuts off when I apply the brakes. Can anyone help me with this problem. It idles just fine but when I apply the brake to put it in reverse it bogs down and completely shuts off. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be due to vacuum or electrical. The breaks are equipped with a vacuum power booster. If the power booster is broken it could induce a very large vacuum leak when you hit the breaks. Try clamping off the hose that is between the power booster and the intake manifold with a set of needle nose vice grips or a hose pinch off tool. If the car stops stalling then you need a new power booster and if it does not then look at possible electrical causes.